# Render a page as a saved HTML file using Rails 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, page-caching

I'm building a simple website generator application in Rails 3.0. I'd like a "publish" action in a controller that works just like an ordinary "show" action, but instead, saves a page as an HTML file in the "public" directory instead of displaying it in the browser. That is, I'd like to use the Rails render mechanism to create a file instead of providing an HTTP response.

What's the best way to do this?

Should I simply add `caches_page :publish` to the controller?

Or use `render_to_string` and `File.new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that page caching using `caches_page` won't work for me because there is no way to show a notification or redirect to another page after caching the page. The method `render_to_string` (suggested by @Grocery) is the way to go. Here's the example controller code:

```
def publish
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  html = render_to_string(:template => "articles/template.html.haml", :layout => 'article' )
  FileUtils.makedirs("#{Rails.root}/public/articles/") unless File.exists?("#{Rails.root}/public/articles/")
  File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/articles/#{@article.filename}.html", 'w') {|f| f.write(html) }
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # publish.html.erb
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `render_to_string` method: http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/render_to_string

You still need to respond from the controller though. Maybe redirect to the page you just saved?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with page caching.

Then if you have editable content, the pages should be automatically generated. You could then write a system task which bundles them up as a web site.

see (whatever)/actionpack/lib/action_controller/caching/pages.rb for instructions.

Comment: This approach is attractive but won't work for me because there is no way to show a notification or redirect to another page after caching the page. Note that the documentation for caches_page is at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html. Note that `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` is required in the `config/environment/development.rb` file during development or you won't see any caching.